# Twitter integration using username and password

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to integrate Twitter in my application, using Twitter4J JAR. But this requires Consumer key, Secret Key, Access tokens.

Is it possible to use just User Name and Password for integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter 4J API does not support User Name and Password.

Please read the following configuration steps for more info:

http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You need the consumer key, secret key and access token to use the Twitter API